# Code enters infinite loop when trying to select features

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to use scikit learn's Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation for a `(5000, 37)` data that has binary class problem and whenever i fit the model the algorithm enters infinite loop.
Currently, i am following this example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html on how to employ this algorithm.

My data is:

```
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
    from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
    
        X = np.random.randint(0,363175645.191632,size=(5000, 37))
        Y = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(37,))
```

What i tried doing to select the features by:

```
    svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
    rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),
                  scoring='accuracy')
    
    rfecv.fit(X, Y)
```

The code hangs and enters infinite loop, however when i try using another algorithm such as ExtraTreesClassifier it works just fine, what is going on, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform svm, because it is distance based, it makes sense to scale your feature variables, especially in your case when they are huge. you can also check out [this intro to svm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf). Using an example dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

Scaler =  StandardScaler()

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=5000, centers=3, shuffle=False,random_state=42)
X = np.concatenate((X,np.random.randint(0,363175645.191632,size=(5000,35))),axis=1)
y = (y==1).astype('int')

X_scaled = Scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

This dataset has only 2 useful variables in the first two columns, as you can see from the plot:

```
plt.scatter(x=X_scaled[:,0],y=X_scaled[:,1],c=['k' if i else 'b' for i in y])
```

[image]

Now we run rfe on scaled data and we can see it returns the first two columns as top variables:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X_scaled, y)

rfecv.ranking_

array([ 1,  2, 17, 28, 33, 22, 23, 26,  6, 19, 20,  4, 10, 25,  3, 27, 11,
        8, 18,  5, 29, 14,  7, 21,  9, 13, 24, 30, 35, 31, 32, 34, 16, 36,
       37, 12, 15])
```

Comment: Should i scale the data, then?

Comment: yes you definitely should. can also try minmax